# Blazor: how to store page state (all components states)?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have 1 full page table component (custom, with column filters, sorting, dynamic loading, "infinite" scrolling and such), then a user clicks "edit" action on a row, it navigates to edit item page. Again, full page. It is a requirement it should visually be separate pages. 2 reasons: one big task a user does is searching, the bigger table, the more data - the better. The second task is updating some records. A single record is a very, very, VERY complex data set, it really needs as much screen space as possible.

The problem is when the user is done editing the record, the app navigates to previous page, but the table is reset, with default filtering, sorting and scrolling position.

Well, I can extract data from the table component and store it in a "pseudo-session" service data. The problem with that is I would have to add a lot of code to the table component - load / save state methods. Really lots of work (for each column filter element, then for column filter rows).

But there is a simpler way. Instead of using separate pages I could just fake it. Place both the table and row edit form on the same page, then just hide one part with JS / CSS. That should work, but IDK, it seems like an ugly hack to me. You render both parts, show one.

BTW, if you hide a component on server side in `.razor` file and then show it again - it's reset. The constructor would be called, all parameters set to default, initial values.

Is there a way to hide a rendered fragment on server side and then show it without causing Blazor to reinitialize it?

Or a "back" function, that shows the last page in exactly the same state it was before navigation occurred?

**UPDATE:**
I just tested the hiding option. Works as charm. Here's how:

```
<div style="@("display: " + (CurrentView == ViewOptions.List ? "block" : "none"))">
    @* My list view here... *@
</div>
@if (CurrentView == ViewOptions.Edit) {
    @* My edit entry view here... *@
}
```

Where `ViewOptions` is just an `enum` containing possible views. The `CurrentView` is of type `ViewOptions`. When `CurrentView` is set to `List` the first part is visible, the second part is not rendered at all. When it changes, the first part is hidden (but not destroyed), the second part is initialized and rendered. As my forms were already done as separate components, they take row identifier as parameter, and they trigger own event allowing to switch the `CurrentView` back to list when the user is done with them. So we basically have 2 virtual pages on 1 page. A hacky solution but it works. And I've done that in 30 minutes instead of couple of hours I would spend to adding load / save features to my `DataTable` component.

Still, maybe there is a better way? Or maybe it's optimal? Like... We have pages (unrelated directly with each others) and... SUBPAGES, like visually separate, but logically directly related to their parent pages.

That gives me an idea... What if I made a component called `Subpage`? :) There is already a component called `Page` in Blazor. So it would like complete the whole concept of pages and subpages. When the pages are not related directly - there's not much sense in navigating "back" to previous page. Or even maintaing the state of unrelated page. But the subpage is directly related. Its content depends on the parent page state. IDK, maybe it's too crazy to go that way ;)

Comment: The problem with the solution "div display or not", is that the component in the div is always instantiated, also the first time, so in the example the component "edit entry" will be instantiated at startup, also if no edit is required, so this is a behavior to pay attention and I think is not the good way to solve the persistance problem.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: You are on the correct lower-effort path, I think.

The "correct" (or, rather, full, complete) way is to implement all the state storage (implement, expose, handle events, store that data somewhere like browser local storage or app state, etc.). As you found, toggling a component with a real `if` resets it - that's where application state comes in - you keep the state in the events realted to changing it, then the next time a component initializes, it reads that state. But you have to implement it all on your own, and that's plenty of work.

So, there are two easier solutions:

- as you found, hide the old content with CSS (if needed), and show the new content on the same page. If you show it in some sort of window/dialog, you may not have to hide the old content at all, though.
- Or, use a component that someone wrote that already has those state capabilities built-in so you can just use them. [Here](https://demos.telerik.com/blazor-ui/grid/persist-state)'s a commercial one I know of.

Comment: Ah, my competition ;) I wondered about using Telerik components, but we needed so many different features, besides I wanted to learn the details, so I made very similar component, but instead of "pages" it uses a kind of "infinite scroller" - so the content is preloaded while user scrolls the table. And many many more features, just not the state management ;)

Comment: Disclosure: I do work for Telerik. That said, the grid has infinite (virtual) scrolling and a ton of other features :)
That said, I do think that what you're doing can work, at least for now. If you start needing that state on other pages or between user sessions, you'll have to go all out and implement an actual component and/or app state.

Comment: Well, my low-effort solutions seems not to work well. It passes my tests, but the clients claim the application starts to slow down and then crashes after a couple of hours of using. A memory leak? And all only because there is no page switching between rendering forms for different records?

Comment: There could be a leak elsewhere not necessarily on the UI portion, a data service caching stuff and never releasing it  sounds a tad more likely to me. If your custom grid component is rather involved it could leak too, especially if some resource cleanup doesn't happen on Dispose when it should (such as clearing refs and js interop handlers)

Comment: Well, the table stays, so it's rather not the source of the problem. But the forms from the other hand - they are in a conditional part of the razor file. So they are destroyed and created. Yes, they use JS interop - I've never read it should be disposed. Is there a documentation on that somewhere? I've never seen IDisposable in Blazor examples, so I thought I should implement IDisposable only if I use some non Blazor disposables inside.

Comment: When the razor component disposes you can clean up a dotnet reference you may have created for it and you can also call js interop to clean up js objects and handlers it used - classes you instantiated such as reusable js components, Dom event handlers that can like up and keep firing, things like that